phreeqpython dissolution and precipitation
Using phreeqpython, which is a wrapper for phreeqc for python. I'm trying to determine how much of a metal dissolves into solution and how much stays in phase.  I'm not seeing an easy way to do this and I'm curious if other have used this library and see a way how to do this.
Here is some sample code of Cu metal being added to an acidic solution
from phreeqpython import PhreeqPython
from pathlib import Path


db_dir = Path('C:/Users/Craig/source/repos/eWasteSim/Database')
db = Path('minteq.dat')

pp = PhreeqPython(database= db, database_directory= db_dir, debug= False)

# this is for simulation purposes, in the model this will be a copy of the block from the left
solidsInlet = {
            'CuMetal'           : 1.0, 
            'Atacamite'         : 0.0, 
            'Cu(OH)2'           : 0.0, 
            'Cuprite'           : 0.0, 
            'Melanothallite'    : 0.0, 
            'Nantokite'         : 0.0, 
            'Tenorite'          : 0.0
}

# This is for simulations purposes, in the model this will be a copy of the block from above
liquidsInlet = solution = pp.add_solution({
                            'units' :   'mol/kgw',
                            'pH'    :   0,
                            'temp'  :   50.0,
                            'redox' :   'pe',
                            'Cu'    :   0,
                            'Cl'    :   '1 charge',
                            'O(0)'  :   10
})

liquidsOulet = liquidsInlet.copy()
liquidsOulet.change_temperature(60)

phasesInlet = [k for k in solidsInlet.keys()]
inletMoles = [v for v in solidsInlet.values()]
SI_Target = [0]*len(phasesInlet)

liquidsOulet.equalize(phases= phasesInlet, to_si= SI_Target, in_phase= inletMoles)

print(' ')
print('Species')
for k, v in liquidsOulet.species.items():
    print(f'{k}                   {v}')

print(' ')
print('Phases')
for k, v in liquidsOulet.phases.items():
    print(f'{k}                   {v}')

Anyone have suggestions on how to determine the total moles in phase?
